# Bash Check for Git Updates on Login

Tags: git, bash, ubuntu, github

I am attempting to check my git repo if there are updates.
I need to do this when I login to my Ubuntu server, so I figured I would modify the /etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available script with the following

It is supposed to `cd` into my repo once it is found, and then compare it to the remote repo, if remote is newer, print the notice.

```
#!/bin/sh

stamp="/var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available"

[ ! -r "$stamp" ] || cat "$stamp"

cd $(find / -wholename '*-Commander*/.git' | xargs -n 1 dirname)

UPSTREAM=${1:-'@{u}'}
LOCAL=$(git rev-parse @)
REMOTE=$(git rev-parse "$UPSTREAM")
BASE=$(git merge-base @ "$UPSTREAM")
echo "----------------------------------------------------------"
echo ""
if [ $LOCAL = $BASE ]; then
    echo "Repo Need to be Updated"
    MEM=$(free -m | grep -oP '\d+' | head -n 1);
    if [ $MEM -lt 2048 ]; then
        echo "Low Mem Check"
    fi;
fi;
echo ""
echo "----------------------------------------------------------"
```

what I am finding is, no matter what.. on login to the machine, it still shows `Repo Need to be Updated`, even if it is up to date.

Note, the repo was pulled as a `sudoer`, logging into the machine does logs in as a normal user at first.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the script you provided you don't check whether remote is newer than local (you wrote that this is what you want). You call `git merge-base` and save it to variable `BASE` an check equality with you local branch. What do you think `BASE` variable contains? It contains common ancestor(s) between two commits you provided. If local branch won't be changed after you pulled from the remote in past, both commits (in variables `LOCAL` and `BASE`) will be the same.**So you are more likely checking whether your local repository did't change** Also message should be printed in non-equality case.

Please have a look at first picture on page [git merge-base example](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base#_discussion). Lets suppose you did in past pull on your local branch, then both remote and local branches will be both at commit `1`. Then later on there will be some commits added to remote, so on this picture it could be branch named `A`, but your local branch won't be changed, so it still points to commit `1`. When you call at this state `git merge-base`, result will be commit `1`, so equality.

I see one more problem Do you fetch remote? AFAIK none of the commands do it automatically.

Comment: you are talking greek to someone who just started using `git`.  i really only know how to pull, commit, and push my changes... that's it.

Comment: @Kevin if you will be more specific about what you don't understand and what you understand, then I can provide an answer. You say you know only `pull`, `commit` and `push` but in your example you used more advanced git commands, so I thought you understand it better. Maybe you should first learn a little bit more about git before using it :) I am affraid I can't explain in this topic how git works.

Comment: @Kevin To summarize changes which should be done: add `git fetch`, change equality check to non-equality check, compare `LOCAL` with `REMOTE`, I don't see any reason to use `BASE`.

Comment: BINGO! :)  Yeah, slowly but surely I'm reading more about `git`  unfortunately, with work, grankids, etc...  time is not always a luxury I have LOL

Comment: @Kevin I understand, time is luxury for me too, work, doughter, etc :)

Answer (score 0):

Single **'='** is attribuition.

Use double **'=='** to compare.

So:

```
if [ $LOCAL == $BASE ]; then
```

Comment: That's not the way it works in Bash. POSIX actually requires that a single = be used for comparison, but Bash also allows 2 = signs.

Comment: @randomdude999 You are right, I didn't notice the */bin/sh* at beginning.

Comment: `=` `==` makes no difference either

Answer (score 0):

The test should be:

```
if [ "$LOCAL" == "$BASE" ]; then
```

Comment: stated in the first answer posted here.  `=` vs `==` made no difference

Comment: The first answer don't have double-quotes